# Plot sample average GDP over time

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to plot a graph from a table.

[df_GDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGjZ7.png)

and here is the code I tried to plot a graph.

```
# Plot sample average GDP over time
x = df_GDP.columns[3:]
y = df_GDP.mean()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title('Global Mean GDP(USD in 2000, adj. for inf.)')
plt.xlabel('Year (C.E.)')
plt.ylabel('GDP mean')
plt.show()
```

And this is what I got:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (58,) and (55,)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first 9 columns of your table are not the data you’re trying to plot, but you’re including most of them in the plot anyway. Fix your first two lines to look like this:

```
x = df_GDP.columns[9:]
y = df_GDP.columns[9:].mean()
```